# Setting Data in to CK Editor from word file

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

My question is as follows.

We are using CKEditor to Show the Content of docx file inside Editor. This CKEditor will be loaded in to our Documnentum Application.

I read the word file and converted it into HTML.
But when I am trying to set the data of that HTML file using

```
      CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData('abc');
```

it is giving me "abc" as value in screen:

```
<%
File file = new File("C:\\TestWordToHtml\\html\\Test.html");
BufferedReader br = null;
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

try {

    String sCurrentLine;

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(sCurrentLine);
        //System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    }
        System.out.println("final content is"+" "+sb.toString());
} 

catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null)br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

String htmdata = sb.toString();`enter code here`
%>
            var abc=htmdata;

          CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData('abc');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is... well - very poor. You have to learn how to pass variable to JS, because in JS `htmdata` will be `undefined`. Then you need to pass that variable to the `setData()` method. Currently you pass there `'abc'` string, not `abc` variable.

So the JS part should look like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(htmdata);
```